# Javascript to resize table AND div inside

Tags: javascript, html, resize

I have a table and a div in it. I have to resize both on load and on window resize.

These Javascript functions (resizeTable and resizeDiv) work if called separately, but resizeDiv doesn't work if called after resizeTable from autoResize.

```
<script>

function autoResize()
{
    var windowSize = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var tableHeight = windowSize * 0.9+'px';
    var rowHeight = (windowSize * 0.9 - 99 - 50)+ "px";
    resizeTable(tableHeight);
    resizeDiv(rowHeight);
}

function resizeTable(tableHeight)
{
    document.getElementById("mainTable") = tableHeight;
}

function resizeDiv(rowHeight)
{
    document.getElementById("cellLogin").style.height = rowHeight;
}

</script>
```

Comment: what is your expected output? if i am not wrong you can easily set `width=90%` and `height=90%` to your table.

Comment: I resize with JS because the height="90%" definitions for the table doesn't render properly in all browsers...
So, I have to force the table resizing in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you've got a bit of a mistake in your code. The line:

```
document.getElementById("mainTable") = tableHeight;
```

Should actually be:

```
document.getElementById("mainTable").style.height = tableHeight;
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBS8j/1/) with the fixed code, seems to give you what you need. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Great! Don't forget, if this answer solved your problem, it's a good idea to mark it off as the selected answer (click the checkmark outline on the left)!